# Minimum number of bits required for each character

Tags: signal-analysis

Assuming that a computer is interfaced with a device that has 210 characters and 
that each character is transmitted using binary words what is the minimum 
number of bits needed to represent each character? To find the minimum is there any specific formula ?

Comment: Depends on the probability distribution of the characters. Read up on Huffman coding if you want to know more.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: add this level homework is not homework :) you do examples if you want, well at least I am taking interest will you complain on that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the formula is

$\lceil \log_2 210 \rceil = 8$

Comment: If the characters are all equally likely, this answer is true. However, see jan's comment on the question above.

Comment: The answer might be different if you are allowed to bundle characters. For example, a bundle of 100 characters can be sent using ceil(log2(210 ^ 100)), which gives 7.72 bit/character.